# error password change in edit profile laravel 7 undefined variable

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-7

i created 2 pages. First it's edit profile and second for change password, this pages and functionnality worked.  when the password change and the other inputs are on separate pages all work and all this changes. but when i try to put the password change on the profile edit i get this error:

Facade\Ignition\Exceptions\ViewException
Undefined variable: user (View: /home/mokoch/Bureau/projetabonnementpayant/resources/views/profile/edit.blade.php)
http://127.0.0.1:8000/profile

MatchOldPassword.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Rules;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Rule;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;
  
class MatchOldPassword implements Rule
{
    /**
     * Determine if the validation rule passes.
     *
     * @param  string  $attribute
     * @param  mixed  $value
     * @return bool
     */
    public function passes($attribute, $value)
    {
        return Hash::check($value, auth()->user()->password);
    }
   
    /**
     * Get the validation error message.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function message()
    {
        return 'The :attribute is match with old password.';
    }
}
```

edit.blade.php

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
<div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header">
                    Update Profile
                </div>

                <div class="card-body">
                    <form method="POST" action="{{ route('profile.edit') }}">
                        @method('patch')
                        @csrf

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="name" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Name') }}</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="name" type="text" class="form-control @error('name') is-invalid @enderror" name="name" value="{{ old('name', $user->name) }}" autocomplete="name" autofocus>

                                @error('name')
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                        <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @enderror
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="firstname" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('firstname') }}</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="firstname" type="text" class="form-control @error('firstname') is-invalid @enderror" name="firstname" value="{{ old('firstname', $user->firstname) }}" autocomplete="firstname" autofocus>

                                @error('firstname')
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                        <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @enderror
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="address" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('address') }}</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="address" type="text" class="form-control @error('address') is-invalid @enderror" address="address" value="{{ old('address', $user->address) }}" autocomplete="address" autofocus>

                                @error('address')
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                        <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @enderror
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="city" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('city') }}</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="city" type="text" class="form-control @error('city') is-invalid @enderror" city="city" value="{{ old('city', $user->city) }}" autocomplete="city" autofocus>

                                @error('city')
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                        <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @enderror
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="phone" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('phone') }}</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="phone" type="text" class="form-control @error('phone') is-invalid @enderror" phone="phone" value="{{ old('phone', $user->phone) }}" autocomplete="phone" autofocus>

                                @error('phone')
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                        <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @enderror
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="profile_image" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('profile_image') }}</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="profile_image" type="text" class="form-control @error('profile_image') is-invalid @enderror" profile_image="profile_image" value="{{ old('profile_image', $user->profile_image) }}" autocomplete="profile_image" autofocus>

                                @error('profile_image')
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                        <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @enderror
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="zipcode" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('zipcode') }}</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="zipcode" type="text" class="form-control @error('zipcode') is-invalid @enderror" zipcode="zipcode" value="{{ old('zipcode', $user->zipcode) }}" autocomplete="zipcode" autofocus>

                                @error('zipcode')
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                        <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @enderror
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="pseudo" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('pseudo') }}</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="pseudo" type="text" class="form-control @error('pseudo') is-invalid @enderror" pseudo="pseudo" value="{{ old('pseudo', $user->pseudo) }}" autocomplete="pseudo" autofocus>

                                @error('pseudo')
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                        <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @enderror
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="birthday" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('birthday') }}</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="birthday" type="date" class="form-control @error('birthday') is-invalid @enderror" birthday="birthday" value="{{ old('birthday', $user->birthday) }}" autocomplete="birthday" autofocus>

                                @error('birthday')
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                        <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @enderror
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="email" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('E-Mail Address') }}</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="email" type="email" class="form-control @error('email') is-invalid @enderror" name="email" value="{{ old('email', $user->email) }}" autocomplete="email">

                                @error('email')
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                        <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @enderror
                            </div>
                        </div>

  
                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="password" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">Current Password</label>
  
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="password" type="password" class="form-control" name="current_password" autocomplete="current-password">
                            </div>
                        </div>
  
                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="password" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">New Password</label>
  
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="new_password" type="password" class="form-control" name="new_password" autocomplete="current-password">
                            </div>
                        </div>
  
                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="password" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">New Confirm Password</label>
    
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="new_confirm_password" type="password" class="form-control" name="new_confirm_password" autocomplete="current-password">
                            </div>
                        </div>
   
                 

                        <div class="form-group row mb-0">
                            <div class="col-md-6 offset-md-4">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                                    Update Profile
                                </button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@endsection
```

changePassword.blade.php

```
@extends('layouts.app')
@section('content')
<div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header">Laravel - Change Password with Current</div>
   
                <div class="card-body">
                    <form method="POST" action="{{ route('profile') }}">
                        @csrf 
   
                         @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
                            <p class="text-danger">{{ $error }}</p>
                         @endforeach 
  
                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="password" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">Current Password</label>
  
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="password" type="password" class="form-control" name="current_password" autocomplete="current-password">
                            </div>
                        </div>
  
                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="password" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">New Password</label>
  
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="new_password" type="password" class="form-control" name="new_password" autocomplete="current-password">
                            </div>
                        </div>
  
                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="password" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">New Confirm Password</label>
    
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="new_confirm_password" type="password" class="form-control" name="new_confirm_password" autocomplete="current-password">
                            </div>
                        </div>
   
                        <div class="form-group row mb-0">
                            <div class="col-md-8 offset-md-4">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                                    Update Password
                                </button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@endsection
```

ChangePasswordController.php

```
<?php
   
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
   
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Rules\MatchOldPassword;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;
use App\User;
  
class ChangePasswordController extends Controller
{
    
    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
    }
   
    /**
     * Show the application dashboard.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Support\Renderable
     */
    public function index()
    {
        return view('profile.edit');
    } 
   
    /**
     * Show the application dashboard.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Support\Renderable
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $request->validate([
            'current_password' => ['required', new MatchOldPassword],
            'new_password' => ['required'],
            'new_confirm_password' => ['same:new_password'],
        ]);
   
        User::find(auth()->user()->id)->update(['password'=> Hash::make($request->new_password)]);
   
        dd('Password change successfully.');
    }
}
```

Web.php

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Web Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register web routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
| contains the "web" middleware group. Now create something great!
|
*/

Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});



Auth::routes();

Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');

Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth'], function () {
    Route::any('profile', 'ProfileController@edit')->name('profile.edit');
});

Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth'], function () {

    Route::get('profile', 'ProfileController@edit')
        ->name('profile.edit');

    Route::patch('profile', 'ProfileController@update')
        ->name('profile.update');

        Route::get('profile', 'ChangePasswordController@index');
        Route::post('profile', 'ChangePasswordController@store');      
});
```

PasswordController.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

class PasswordController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\View\Factory|\Illuminate\View\View
     */
    public function edit()
    {
        return view('profile.edit');
    }
}
```

UpdateProfileRequest.php controller

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class UpdateProfileRequest extends Controller
{
 /**
 * Update user's profile
 *
 * @param  UpdateProfileRequest $request
 * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Support\Renderable
 */
public function update(UpdateProfileRequest $request)
{
    $request->user()->update(
        $request->all()
    );

    return redirect()->route('profile.edit');
}
}
```

UpdateProfileRequest.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Requests;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Validation\Rule;

class UpdateProfileRequest extends FormRequest
{
    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function authorize()
    {
        return Auth::check();
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'name' => [
                'required', 'string', 'max:255'
            ],
            'username' => [
                'required', 'string', 'max:255',
                Rule::unique('users', 'username')->ignore(Auth::user()->id)
            ],
            'email' => [
                'required', 'email', 'max:255',
                Rule::unique('users', 'email')->ignore(Auth::user()->id)
            ],
        ];
    }
}
```

Someone can help me leave this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error is pretty straight forward, You are using an undefined variable.

You can either add the variable:

```php
public function edit()
{
    return view('profile.edit', ['user' => auth()->user()]);
}
```

Or inside your blade use `auth()->user()` directly instead of `$user`

Comment: I added this in Changepasswordcontroller and i changed this in passwordcontroller and nothing changing :/

Comment: Everywhere you are returning view('profile.edit') you need to add the user variable. [Read this](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/controllers#defining-controllers)

Comment: I believe [this](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent#updates) will solve your problem. I suggest you read Laravel documentation it will help you.